# Continuous action by profinite completion of a group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, infinite-groups, profinite-groups

I'm working on a problem involving diagram dependence of a specific group action. It turns out that taking the profinite completion of the group will allow me to speak from a point of universality in some sense. Suppose $G$ is a group which acts continuously on a profinite space $X$. Is it true that the profinite completion $\hat{G}$ of $G$ also acts continuously on $X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $G$ be any group that is not residually finite, let $X=\{0,1\}^G$ and let $G$ act on $X$ by permuting the coordinates by left translation.  The action of $G$ on $X$ is faithful, but the canonical map from $G$ to its profinite completion is not injective, so the action cannot factor through the profinite completion.  (More generally, this shows that any group can act faithfully on a profinite space, so having such an action doesn't tell you anything useful about the group on its own.)

Comment: Is it true for residually finite groups?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  For instance, taking my example with $G=\mathbb{Z}$, I don't see any reason to expect to have a canonical extension to $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Thanks, I have some more specific questions, but I'll make another post for that since they consider a particular construction. If you want to comment, I'll request an answer : )

Comment: Never mind, there won't be another post. I've found a large collection of cases when this is true and it holds for the problem I am working on, and in fact suffices to characterize algebraically connected profinite quandles and is independent of diagram.